# Nested JSON Data

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access nested JSON data inside a JSON using jQuery but I seem to be missing something. I keep getting console errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '34' in [{'1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png'}]` so I know my issue has to do something with the nested data. I've tried several different ways to get around this which I commented in my jsfiddle link below.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if my nested data is simply formatted wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/hg6631am/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = [{  
      "title":"Vendor Website",
      "desc":"Vendor Website Vendor Website Vendor Website",
      "album":"[{'1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png'}]",
      "version":"1.0"
   },
   {  
      "title":"Vendor Profile",
      "desc":"Vendor Profile Vendor Profile Vendor Profile",
      "album":"[{'1.png','2.png','3.png'}]",
      "version":"1.0"
   }];
  $.each(json,function(k,v) {
      $('#box').append("<h3>Title "+k+": "+v.title+"</h3>"); 
      $('#box').append("<h3>Album "+k+": "+v.album+"</h3>");
      $.each(v.album,function(i,x) {
          $('box').append("<h3>Album "+k+", Value #"+i+": "+x); 
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues. Please change

```
$('box').append("<h3>Album "+k+", Value #"+i+": "+x);
```

to

```
$('#box').append("<h3>Album "+k+", Value #"+i+": "+x);
```

You should have an array instead of a *string of an array with an object* in your JSON. Please change

```
"album":"[{'1.png','2.png','3.png', '4.png'}]",
```

to

```
"album":['1.png','2.png','3.png', '4.png'],
```

and do the same to the other album entry below.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hg6631am/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
 "album":"[{'1.png','2.png','3.png'}]",
```

Needs to be formated as:

```
 "album":['1.png','2.png','3.png'],
```